# It's a 4x and card game mix possible?

Tags: game-design

I'm making a little research in a mix between 4x game and cards games. Do you think is possible?

I'm an hobbyist game developer and I like both 4x (Civilization, Master of Orion, Crusader Kings 2) video games, but I found frustrating how much micro-management you should put into these games. I mean, it's fun to play sometimes, but other times I'd like to have a more "macro" control over game, only set objectives and stop.
Then my idea is to create mix between a 4x game and a card games, where every card player can play is an action (send enterprise to explore a sector, create a new colony, spy on one enemy, etc..).

I'd like to share with someone else these ideas!
I've also build a little googe module to get some "data" from other people, here:

http://goo.gl/forms/kM6mtAjgOc

I will share results with every participants!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: I'd like also to get more feedback, when do you have time, could you follow google forms link ? Thanks!

Comment: This site is about questions that can be definitively answered. An answer to this question would either be "It is my opinion that it can" or "Yes, here's one", both of which can result in lots of equally valid answers. Also, the majority of your question is promoting your board game and soliciting strangers to help. This site is not intended for that.

Comment: Hello everyone! I'm closing this survey and I'm going to email to every participant survey result and after two weeks I will publish results for everyone.
Thanks, It's amazing your support!

Comment: This no longer seems so opinion based in light of Benjamin Cosman's definite answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - [Impulse](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/144239/impulse) is such a game.

> Impulse is a quick-playing 4X game set in space with the game board being composed of cards that have actions on them. Players also have cards in hand...